# AVAssetExportSession estimatedOutputFileLength throws exception: 'Invalid presetName'

Tags: ios, avfoundation

When I try to get estimated file size using `AVAssetExportSession` instance `estimatedOutputFileLength` the app throws exception with reason `'Invalid presetName'`. Session initialized with `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` preset. Tested on iPod touch 4G with iOS 6.x

Comment: post the full code sample. I have seen the issue of nil being returned but not your issue.